# Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = 'PlatformFile in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to post PaltformFiles to the server using Multipart Requests but keep getting the above error for some strange reason. I would like to know what I can do to resolve this error. The code I have written is given below.

File Picker Method:

```
onTap: () async {
                            final filePickerOne = await FilePicker.platform
                                .pickFiles(
                                    type: FileType.custom,
                                    allowedExtensions: [
                                  'pdf',
                                  'jpg',
                                  'jpeg',
                                  'png'
                                ]);
                            if (filePickerOne == null) return;

                            final fileOne = filePickerOne.files.first;
                            openFile(fileOne);
                            print('Name: ${fileOne.name}');

                            setState(() {
                              fileOneName = fileOne.name;
                              panDoc = fileOne;
                            });

                            print('Bytes: ${fileOne.bytes}');
                            print('Size: ${fileOne.size}');
                            print('Extension: ${fileOne.extension}');
                            print('Path: ${fileOne.path}');
```

The API Request:

```
Future<void> postMethod(
      String? organizationName,
      String? telephoneNumberOne,
      String? telephoneNumberTwo,
      String? companyPanCard,
      PlatformFile? panCard,
      String? aadharUdyamUdoyog,
      PlatformFile? aadharCard,
      String? gstNumber) async {
    SharedPreferences localStorage = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    // final File filePanCard = File(panCard!.path.toString());
    // final File fileAadharCard = File(aadharCard!.path.toString());
    final url = Uri.parse(baseUrl + 'api/vendor/profile/business/');
    var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', url);
    request.headers
        .addAll({'Authorization': 'Bearer ${localStorage.getString('token')}'});
    request.fields['org_name'] = organizationName!;
    request.fields['telephone_1'] = telephoneNumberOne!;
    request.fields['telephone_2'] = telephoneNumberTwo!;
    request.fields['company_pancard'] = companyPanCard!;
    request.files.add(http.MultipartFile.fromBytes(
        'company_pancard_doc', File(panCard!.toString()).readAsBytesSync())); //This is where the error gets thrown
    request.fields['adhar_udyam_udoyog'] = aadharUdyamUdoyog!;
    request.files.add(http.MultipartFile.fromBytes('adhar_udyam_udoyog_doc',
        File(aadharCard!.toString()).readAsBytesSync()));  //Resolving the aboe error will hopefully resolve this one as well.
    request.fields['gst_number'] = gstNumber!;

    var response = await request.send();

    print('Response: $response');

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print('Uploaded');
    } else {
      print('Failed');
    }
  }
```

Any Ideas? Do let me know If you more info.

Comment: What is the exact error ? usually there is an error code / reason after the file path

Comment: I think it should be panCard!.path! instead of panCard!.toString()

Comment: @HichemBenali The Error code is 400. The full error is Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = 'PlatformFile(path /data/user/0/com.example.tanvi_vendor/cache/file_picker/FB_IMG_1653051736385.jpg, name: FB_IMG_1653051736385.jpg, bytes: null, readStream: null, size: 134807)' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)

Comment: @mohamed.oussous Although Doing  panCard!.path! doesn't give me the above error, it gives me 400 as the error code.